# How can I write a flutter/dart web plugin without need to register with `Registrar`?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been writing an FFI flutter package. FFI packages do not use `MethodChannel` and also their `registerWith` method does not take `Registrar` as a parameter. Then, I needed to use the plugin on the web, so I compiled it into WASM with JS bindings and made it also work on the web. There are very few decent docs/tutorials on how to write dart plugins, so I took the `url_launcher` as an example. They use `MethodChannels` in their web implementation and this is the only way I found to do plugins for the web. But this makes absolutely no sense for me. My registerWith function looks like this:

```
  static void registerWith(Registrar _) =>
      MyPluginPlatform.instance = MyPluginWeb._();
```

So, are there any ways to get rid of the `Registrar` in the flutter web plugin?

The possible ways for me seem:

- To make a fake `flutter_web_plugins` with the empty `Registrar` implementation. But this is not an option, because package is published to pub.dev and the fake package should keep the exact `flutter_web_plugins` name, so cannot be published.
- To somehow modify `.dart_tool/dartpad/web_plugin_registrant.dart` at the build step. I don't know anything about custom build steps in dart and not sure if it's even possible.
- To delegate includance of the `flutter_web_plugins` for the app. This is not appropriate if I want my plugin to be compatible with non-flutter dart apps.

As a temporary fix, I changed parameter type of the `registerWith` to `dynamic` and moved the includance of the `flutter_web_plugins` into the main plugin which already includes flutter as a dependency. But this does not seem a good enough option for me.